# Index was outside the bounds of the array vb.net n mapwingis

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am making a map app with `VB.net` and `Mapwingis`.
I want to save the map data with an array, but any error.
this code :

```
 Dim scheme As New MapWinGIS.ColorScheme

    Dim idx As Integer
    idx = FormMain.TreeViewLayer.Nodes.IndexOf(FormMain.TreeViewLayer.SelectedNode)
    sf = FormMain.AxMapMain.get_Shapefile(idx)
    mainMapHandler = FormMain.AxMapMain.AddLayer(sf, True)
    sf = FormMain.AxMapMain.get_Shapefile(mainMapHandler)
    Dim fieldName As Integer
    fieldName = CBSymVarNameUnique.SelectedIndex
    sf.Categories.Generate(fieldName, MapWinGIS.tkClassificationType.ctUniqueValues, 0)
    filcol = Convert.ToUInt32(RGB(255, 255, 255))

    filcol2 = Convert.ToUInt32(RGB(0, 0, 255))
    scheme.SetColors(filcol, filcol2)

    Dim nama2() As String = New String() {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To sf.Categories.Count - 1
        Dim category As MapWinGIS.ShapefileCategory = sf.Categories.Item(i)
        nama2(i) = category.Name.Substring(category.Name.IndexOf("=") + 1) 'error here
    Next
```

Could you help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
 Dim nama2() As String = New String() {}
```

you declare an array of string without any space to store strings. The `Length` of this array is zero.

Of course when you write

```
 nama2(i) = category.Name.Substring(.....)
```

the code crashes because there is no space to store elements in the array

You need to declare the array with the appropriare space to store the strings that you plan to retrieve

```
 Dim nama2(sf.Categories.Count-1) As String
```

However I suggest to use a `List(Of String)` and add the elements to this list as you need

```
Dim nama2 = New List(Of String)()
For i As Integer = 0 To sf.Categories.Count - 1
    Dim category As MapWinGIS.ShapefileCategory = sf.Categories.Item(i)
    nama2.Add(category.Name.Substring(category.Name.IndexOf("="))
Next
```

Comment: Right. Too long time without VB... (now developing in Android and using Blender).

Comment: One more reason to use `List(Of String)`

Comment: steve, page not found